# Is it correct to use suspend fun that returns with context value inside another suspend fun that returns with context value?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, coroutinescope

At the moment I am using in my app suspend fun such as getSessionId(), getLocationLatitude(), getLocationLongitude(), getActionDateTime() and getUserName() which returns some values from the database using return withContext(ioDispatcher).

Then, I am calling these functions in my private fun testViewModelScope() inside the viewModelScope.launch() {
to get these values ready for use. However, I released that instantiating/getting all these values inside the private fun testViewModelScope() grows the line of code rapidly and makes the code less readable.

For that reason, I created another suspend fun getMainActivityDataClassObject() that return@withContext
data class that includes all the information need it. All values are called from the suspend fun such as getSessionId() and others. The function is used in the private fun testViewModelScope() inside the viewModelScope.launch() {.

I am trying to improve my knowledge about the main-safe use, return@withContext and viewModelScope.launch().

**My first question is:**

Is it correct to use suspend fun with return@withContext inside another suspend fun with return@withContext?

**My second question is:**

Is it anything in my code that I can improve?

**My third question is:**

Is it any better way to do it?

**Repository:**

```
override suspend fun getSessionId(): Int? {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        firstDao.getSessionId()
    }
}


override suspend fun getLocationLatitude(): String? {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        firstDao.getLocationLatitude()
    }
}

override suspend fun getLocationLongitude(): String? {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        firstDao.getLocationLongitude()
    }
}

override suspend fun getActionDateTime(): String? {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        firstDao.getActionDateTime()
    }
}

override suspend fun getUserName(): String? {
    return withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        firstDao.getUserName()
    }
}

override suspend fun getMainActivityDataClassObject(): MainActivityDataObjectClass = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
    val sessionId = getSessionId()
    val latitude = getLocationLatitude()
    val longitude = getLocationLongitude()
    val actionDateTime = getActionDateTime()
    val userName = getUserName()
    val dataObject = MainActivityDataObjectClass(
        sessionId,latitude,longitude,actionDateTime,userName
    )
   return@withContext dataObject
}
```

**Data Class**

```
@Parcelize
data class MainActivityDataObjectClass(
    var sessionId: Int?,
    var latitude: String?,
    var longitude: String?,
    var actionDateTime: String?,
    var userName: String?,
) : Parcelable
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private fun testViewModelScope() {
    viewModelScope.launch() {

        try {

            // TODO APPROACH NO 1
            val sessionId = mainActivityRepository.getSessionId()
            val latitude = mainActivityRepository.getLocationLatitude()
            val longitude = mainActivityRepository.getLocationLongitude()
            val actionDateTime = mainActivityRepository.getActionDateTime()
            val userName = mainActivityRepository.getUserName()

            // TODO APPROACH NO 2
            val dataObject = mainActivityRepository.getMainActivityDataClassObject()
            
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            throw e
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
It is unnecessary to use `withContext` to call a suspend function. Using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` is for calling *blocking* code. Suspend functions by convention must not block. None of the suspend functions from Google, Jetpack, Square, Kotlinx, etc. libraries block. This includes Room DAO functions that you mark with the `suspend` keyword.

Question 2 and 3:
Approach 2 versus 3 is just a matter opinion and you don’t show what you do with your code next so it’s hard to say.

It’s usually wrong to do a blanket catch of all Exceptions like you are doing. You should be responding to expected exceptions like IOException somewhere high up so you can inform the user or recover.

Catching and rethrowing CancellationExceptions can be a bit of a gotcha. I think it’s ok here, but there are APIs (especially ones defined in Java) that can throw them for reasons other than cancelling a coroutine. Just beware for that possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I may misunderstand some ideas about using withContext and suspend, however, according to the [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety) website, you can use suspend keyword to enforce a function to be called from within a coroutine ( testViewModelScope ).

Also, I am using withContext(ioDispatcher) for main-safe reasons because I making access to the DB (not Room I am using SugarORM unfortunately).
[developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv#main-safety)

Comment: To answer your question

1,
Yes, you are right. In my live app, I inform the user about the state via Observer in the Activity (Exception, Error, Loading, Successful etc). 

2,
After I have all values in the testViewModelScope then I am creating Object from it and then I am creating JSON String using the Object. After that, I am using the JSON String to be sent as part of the Body that I am sending using  POST.

Comment: Proper **non-blocking** suspend functions **are** main safe, without `withContext`. In the example you linked, they use `withContext` to wrap only the part of the coroutine that calls **blocking** code, as their comment in the example says. If you're calling blocking functions from SugarORM, all your getter functions are correct to use `withContext` except for that last one `getMainActivityDataClassObject()` that calls the other suspend functions.

Comment: It's correct that you use `withContext` in those suspend functions to call blocking code, and that's what makes your suspend functions fit the convention that they are non-blocking. So `getMainActivityDataClassObject()` can follow the rule I said in my answer, that it does **not** need `withContext()` because it is not calling blocking code.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response. That helps me to learn something new.  Is that the solution that you have in mind?

override suspend fun getMainActivityDataClassObject(): MainActivityDataObjectClass  {
    val sessionId = getSessionId()
    val latitude = getLocationLatitude()
    val longitude = getLocationLongitude()
    val actionDateTime = getActionDateTime()
    val userName = getUserName()
    val dataObject = MainActivityDataObjectClass(
        sessionId,latitude,longitude,actionDateTime,userName
    )
   return dataObject
}

Comment: Yes. I also suggest using a more descripting name of the class than MainActivityDataObjectClass or otherwise moving this function to your ViewModel. Because the Repository layer should not be aware of the UI layer (activity) if you're trying to practice good encapsulation. Code will be easier to maintain and modify for future changes if you practice good encapsulation. (Also, it's weird to have the word "Class" in a class name because if that were a convention, every single class would have "Class" at the end of its name.)